# JS: replace all img src relative urls to absolute

Tags: javascript, regex

I originally had a function which looked like this:

```
url = url.replace(new RegExp("img src=\"/", 'g'), "img src=\"" + config.baseSPDomain + "/");
```

which worked pretty okay but then it broke when a someone would write the "alt" altribute behind the img tag. for example:

```
<img alt="test" img="/test.jpg" />
```

So I rewote my regular expression to handle this case. I replaced it with the following code:

```
  url = url.replace(new RegExp("<img(.*)src=\"", 'g'), "<img src=\"" + config.baseSPDomain + "/");
```

which works great but somehow it truncates the rest of the string. and I do not know why.

Below is the sample input

old url: before parsing

```
<div class="ExternalClassA32A15F1FF86483AAF71DA3710DFEFCF">
  <p>​</p>
  <p>dit is een image zonder alt<br></p>
  <p>
    <img src="/sites/Nieuwsportaal/PublishingImages/hall-of-fame.png" alt="" style="margin&#58;5px;" />
    <br>
  </p>
  <p>
    <br>
  </p>
  <p>dit is een image met alt
    <br>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="/sites/Nieuwsportaal/PublishingImages/Nieuwsberichten/Barcelona%20beach.jpg" alt="Barcelona beach.jpg" style="margin&#58;5px;" /><br>
  </p>
  <p><br>
  </p>
  <p><br>
  </p>
  <p>dit is een image met alt<br>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="/sites/Nieuwsportaal/PublishingImages/Nieuwsberichten/app1.jpg" alt="app1.jpg" style="margin&#58;5px;" /><br>
  </p>
</div>
```

New url: after parsing

```
<div class="ExternalClassA32A15F1FF86483AAF71DA3710DFEFCF">
  <p>​</p>
  <p>dit is een image zonder alt<br>
  </p>
  <p>
    <img src="https://one365dev2.sharepoint.com//sites/Nieuwsportaal/PublishingImages/Nieuwsberichten/app1.jpg" alt="app1.jpg" style="margin&#58;5px;" /><b>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: You really don't need to use regular expressions for this; the `HTMLImgElement.src` will always return the absolute URL for an `<img>` element (whereas the `HTMLImgElement.getAttribute('src')` will return whatever URL was set in the attribute).

Comment: Unfortunetely that won't work as the data comes from an API call of sharepoint and I only get a paragraph of text back.

Comment: Further to the above, why are you using relative URLs at all, if you then want every single client that loads your page to replace that relative URL with an absolute URL either after the image has already been loaded or as it's already trying to load? Having just seen your response, you may want to [edit] that point into the question, and trim out as much of the irrelevant code as possible (the empty `<p>`, and the `<br>`, elements for example).

Comment: Your main problem is that `img(.*)src` is greedy. Change to `img(.*?)src` and it **might** work for you. Tread lightly when parsing HTML with regex. It *can* be an exelent alternative, but mostly it's just stupid. ;)

Comment: Check DOMParser https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser

Comment: @ClasG that worked great. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, parsing HTML with regex always get's a lot of down votes and critique (mostly justified), so you should think twice before doing it. For some cases it may be a valid solution though.

Your specific problem is that the greedy `.*` matches all from the first `img` to the last. Changing it to non-greedy, `.*?`, will do the trick.

To make it a little bit less vulnerable you could change it to `[^"]*?` and thus match only non quotes.

But it's still no way near a 100% solution.